# Яке значення має вислів "розкатати губу"?

Tags: переклад

В українській мові є цікавий вислів: "розкатати губу".

В російській мові є альтернатива - раскатать губу. Вона має таке значення:

> Раскатывать (раскатать) губу (губы) на что-л. — сильно захотеть чего-л. заведомо невозможного, нереального, напр.: Губки-то на квартиру раскатал, а теперь закатай обратно.

В словопедії сказано:

> *Губу підкотити*, жрм. Не мріяти про нездійсненне, неможливе.
>   Губу (губи) розкатати, жрм. 1) Багато хотіти, та нічого не мати. 2) Сварити, лаяти. - Ну й губу розкатала! Аж заходиться.

То яке ж цих значень вірне (мріяти про неможливе чи сварити)?

Answer (score 3):

У [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53395/374203.html) цей вираз наводиться як сленговий. Надано таке пояснення:

> ГУБА  1  (-и) ж.  ♦ Губу підкотити, жрм. Не мріяти про нездійсненне,
>   неможливе. ФССГД, 78. 
>   **Губу (губи) розкатати**, жрм. 1) Багато хотіти, та нічого не мати. 2) Сварити, лаяти. - Ну й губу розкатала! Аж заходиться. ФССГД, 78.

Answer (score 2):

Тут взагалі питання наскільки цей вислів український. В обговоренні на [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1709) пропонують

- Забажала гиря кісничків -- лиса/коротко стрижена голова захотіла, щоб в косу вплели стрічки.

> ГИ́РЯВИЙ, а, е, діал.
>
> 1. *зневажл.* З стриженою, бритою головою. Не вспіє гирява дівка й коси собі заплести (як ми вернемось додому) (Номис, 1864, № 13885);
>    //  У знач. ім. гирявий, вого, *чол.* Той, у кого стрижена, брита голова. У його стільки землі, як у гирявого чуприни (Словник Грінченка);
>    // Вбогий, нужденний. Таке вже гиряве моє щастя (Словник Грінченка): Ти кажеш, недоречні Слова оці пишу.. Та, бач, буває ж в мові Завжди воно отак, То злота шмат чудовий, То гирявий п'ятак (Павло Усенко, Листя.., 1956, 181).

На [словник.ua](https://slovnyk.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1856):

> На чуже добро ще змалку **рота роззявляє** (Сава Голованівський);
>
> В українській мові такий зміст можна віддати звичайними дієсловами **зазіхати, важити, важитися, заздритися, квапитися, ласитися, надитися**. З фразеологічних зворотів спали на думку **поривати очі, роззявляти рота, слина тече (потекла, котиться, покотилася, набігає на язик)**.